# APK file not generated in alpha anywhere cordova cli builder

Tags: cordova, apk

I was trying to generated the .apk file from cordova cli builder in Alpha Anywhere. I am using the latest AA build as in October 6 (Build 7086). I wish to use the QR generated code the way I always did when using the Phonegap builder. I cannot find good reference for this and decided to call for help from any Alphaholic out here.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You might have a look at VoltBuilder. It generates apk files (and QR Codes linking to them), much like PhoneGap did.

Answer (score 0):

My bad!! Actually the apk. file do exist in my webroot. I can copy and install the app in my mobile phone and at least it works until before the latest build 7295. I realized some changes need to be done and at the moment still trying to figure it out.